# How to translate the files using google translator via selenium

Tags: java

I came across https://translate.google.com/ which translates given text to the desired language.

I have nearly 2,000 files, each file 300 KB.

Currently I need to open each file, paste the text and translate it by above web-site then save it.

Is there a way to automate for the 2,000 files by reading and sending portions of files and finally append to the files? Repeat same for all files.

Doubts:

1. Will the IP address be blocked?
2. Is it illegal to use selenium for this purpose?
3. Is there a legal automated way to translate using the above free service?

If nothing is possible, I need to do it manually.

please advise.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1- I think not

2- No, its no illegal

3- Yes, you can use the google translate api:

```
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/
single?
client=gtx
&sl=<SOURCE LANGUAGE, can be auto>
&tl=<TARGUET LANGUAGE, cannot be auto>
&dt=t
&q=<TEXT>
```

References: https://cloud.google.com/translate/

Comment: This one shows the pricing..However the link which i shared is online service without registration. Please re-check your posted link.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check the Google API Cloud Translation:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

and the REST API reference:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/

Comment: The cloud API associated with cost. The above link which i have pasted is a free online service which i am trying to use via programming.